# How to tell websocket server to accept incoming connections?

Tags: phpwebsocket

I have started using the websocket php example in http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ It works pretty well on localhost but unfortunately, no client other than localhost can connect to the websocket server. And whenever I change the path to something like http://10.27.50.25:8787/client.html, it does not let the client to connect. Does anyone have any idea/sample about how to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sheepy is right, this is probably a firewall issue, but also it is worth trying to pass `(int) 0` in as the address to bind to for the server-side listen socket - this binds to all available interfaces. PS. I know the PHP manual says you should pass in `'0.0.0.0'` to do this, but this doesn't always work on win32. Passing in `0` seems to work everywhere I have ever tried it

Comment: I have set the address to 0 but again no change.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a crossdomain problem.  Modern browsers prevent access to hosts other than the one where the page loaded from.  You can get around it by providing JSON as an output then using jQuery Ajax JSON parsing.

Comment: Yes. If it's not a firewall issue, and if the tests are conducted from local, then there's a good chance the problem is cross domain configuration. However using AJAX as workaround not only beat the purpose of websockets, it also waste the build-in cross domain design of websocket.